# Why my bigquery sql is not returning any result?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am querying on public dataset in bigquery. The sql is valid and bigquery UI showing message "This query will process 15.9 MB when run." but still I am getting blank output screenshot attached [BigQuery result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3A7eY.png).

Please find below the details of project.
project - bigquery-public-data
dataset - google_analytics_sample
table - ga_sessions_20170801

I am using SELECT statement to get the all columns result.

```
    SELECT visitorId,
visitNumber,
visitId,
visitStartTime,
date,
totals.visits,
totals.hits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
totals.bounces,
totals.transactions,
totals.transactionRevenue,
totals.newVisits,
totals.screenviews,
totals.uniqueScreenviews,
totals.timeOnScreen,
totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
totals.sessionQualityDim,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.source,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
trafficSource.campaignCode,
device.browser,
device.browserVersion,
device.browserSize,
device.operatingSystem,
device.operatingSystemVersion,
device.isMobile,
device.mobileDeviceBranding,
device.mobileDeviceModel,
device.mobileInputSelector,
device.mobileDeviceInfo,
device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
device.flashVersion,
device.javaEnabled,
device.language,
device.screenColors,
device.screenResolution,
device.deviceCategory,
geoNetwork.continent,
geoNetwork.subContinent,
geoNetwork.country,
geoNetwork.region,
geoNetwork.metro,
geoNetwork.city,
geoNetwork.cityId,
geoNetwork.networkDomain,
geoNetwork.latitude,
geoNetwork.longitude,
geoNetwork.networkLocation,
cd.index,
cd.value,
h.hitNumber,
h.time,
h.hour,
h.minute,
h.isSecure,
h.isInteraction,
h.isEntrance,
h.isExit,
h.referer,
h.page.pagePath,
h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.transaction.transactionId,
h.transaction.transactionRevenue as tRevenue,
h.transaction.transactionTax,
h.transaction.transactionShipping,
h.transaction.affiliation,
h.transaction.currencyCode,
h.transaction.localTransactionRevenue,
h.transaction.localTransactionTax,
h.transaction.localTransactionShipping,
h.transaction.transactionCoupon,
h.item.transactionId as tId,
h.item.productName,
h.item.productCategory,
h.item.productSku,
h.item.itemQuantity,
h.item.itemRevenue,
h.item.currencyCode as cCode,
h.item.localItemRevenue,
h.contentInfo.contentDescription,
h.appInfo.name,
h.appInfo.version,
h.appInfo.id,
h.appInfo.installerId,
h.appInfo.appInstallerId,
h.appInfo.appName,
h.appInfo.appVersion,
h.appInfo.appId,
h.appInfo.screenName,
h.appInfo.landingScreenName,
h.appInfo.exitScreenName,
h.appInfo.screenDepth,
h.exceptionInfo.description,
h.exceptionInfo.isFatal,
h.exceptionInfo.exceptions,
h.exceptionInfo.fatalExceptions,
h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
h.eventInfo.eventAction,
h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
h.eventInfo.eventValue,
hp.productSKU as pSKU,
hp.v2ProductName,
hp.v2ProductCategory,
hp.productVariant,
hp.productBrand,
hp.productRevenue,
hp.localProductRevenue,
hp.productPrice,
hp.localProductPrice,
hp.productQuantity,
hp.productRefundAmount,
hp.localProductRefundAmount,
hp.isImpression,
hp.isClick,
hpc.index as hpcIndex,
hpc.value as hpcValue,
hpCustomMetrics.index as cusomMetricsIndex,
hpCustomMetrics.value as cusomMetricsValue,
hp.productListName,
hp.productListPosition,
hp.productCouponCode,
hpromotion.promoId, 
hpromotion.promoName,
hpromotion.promoCreative,
hpromotion.promoPosition,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick,
h.refund.refundAmount,
h.refund.localRefundAmount,
h.eCommerceAction.action_type,
h.eCommerceAction.step,
h.eCommerceAction.option,
hExperiment.experimentId,
hExperiment.experimentVariant,
h.publisher.dfpClicks,
h.publisher.dfpImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpQueries,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.dfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxClicks,
h.publisher.adxImpressions,
h.publisher.adxMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxQueries,
h.publisher.adxRevenue,
h.publisher.adxViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsMatched,
h.publisher.viewableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.measurableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.adsPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsClicked,
h.publisher.adsRevenue,
h.publisher.dfpAdGroup,
h.publisher.dfpAdUnits,
h.publisher.dfpNetworkId,
hcustomVariables.index as hcustomVariableIndex,
hcustomVariables.customVarName,
hcustomVariables.customVarValue,
hcustomDimensions.index as customDimensionsIndex,
hcustomDimensions.value as customDimensionsvalue,
hcustomMetrics.index as hcustoMetricsIndex,
hcustomMetrics.value as hcustomMetricsValue,
h.type,
h.social.socialInteractionNetwork,
h.social.socialInteractionAction,
h.social.socialInteractions,
h.social.socialInteractionTarget,
h.social.socialNetwork,
h.social.uniqueSocialInteractions,
h.social.hasSocialSourceReferral,
h.social.socialInteractionNetworkAction,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
h.latencyTracking.pageDownloadTime,
h.latencyTracking.redirectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.speedMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domainLookupTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime,
h.latencyTracking.domLatencyMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime,
h.latencyTracking.domContentLoadedTime,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingValue,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingSample,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingVariable,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingCategory,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel,
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName,   
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews5,
h.dataSource,
hpublisher.dfpClicks as hpublisherDfpclicks,
hpublisher.dfpImpressions as hpublisherDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpQueries as hpublisherDfpQueries,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.dfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpPagesViewed as hpublisherDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxClicks as hpublisherAdxClicks,
hpublisher.adxImpressions as hpublisherAdxImpressions,
hpublisher.adxMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxQueries as hpublisherAdxQueries,
hpublisher.adxRevenue as hpublisherAdxRevenue,
hpublisher.adxViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsViewed as hpublisherAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsViewed as hpublisherAdsUnitsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsMatched as hpublisherAdsUnitsMatched,
hpublisher.viewableAdsViewed as hpublisherViewableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.measurableAdsViewed as hpublisherMeasurableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsClicked as hpublisherAdsClicked,
hpublisher.adsRevenue as hpublisherAdsRevenue,
hpublisher.dfpAdGroup as hpublisherDfpAdGroup,
hpublisher.dfpAdUnits as hpublisherDfpAdUnits,
hpublisher.dfpNetworkId as hpublisherDfpNetworkId,
fullVisitorId,
userId,
clientId,
channelGrouping,
socialEngagementType


FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd,
UNNEST(hits) as h,
UNNEST(h.product) as hp,
UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc,
UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics,
UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion,
UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment,
UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables,
UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions,
UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics,
UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher


LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Can you share the query which you using ?

Comment: Is it because there's nothing in UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc,
UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics,
UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion?

Comment: @Bobbylank that's fine but when I am using above query with all columns of given table then also,I'm getting blank output and when I am not involving above columns with the columns that has value in it then I'm able to see the output

Answer (score 1):

Indeed you have empty values as mentioned by @Bobbylank

This is an SQL example of how to resolve this (You need to move the inner ARRAY into the `SELECT` part)

```
SELECT 
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
hp.productSKU as pSKU,
hp.customDimensions,
(SELECT hpc.index
   FROM UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
UNNEST(hits) as h,
UNNEST(h.product) as hp
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I am querying each column value of the "ga_sessions_20170801" table and is counting upto 306 column after UNNESTING array and RECORD column.It is giving me result upto 120 columns level but I am not able to get all the value of column.

Comment: As asked by @SANN3 please provide the full `SELECT` statement you are using and describe in more details in your question what is not working for you

Comment: I have attached sql query sample.I cannot attach full sql as it is contain 306 column and it will be difficult to read.

Comment: It's very hard for anyone to help more than @TamirKlein has if you can't post the full query

Comment: @sam If my example help you solve your entire query simply mark this answer as the solution so we know we are done with this topic

Comment: @Bobbylank,@Tamir. I have updated the question with full query.

Comment: @sam the issue is that you have an empty array on your inner nest. Use the SQL example in my answer which solve this problem to modify your entire query, If this is still not working post the new modified SQL

Comment: @TamirKlein, so, in this case I am seeing there are many blank array, to get my above query working I need to move the blank array part in inner SELECT?

Comment: @TamirKlein, I have up-voted your answer. I don't have reputation of 15 or above. so my vote will not be publicly visible.May be I need to dig more regarding UNNEST,array,struct then only I can understand in better way.Anyway,thank you for your help.

Comment: Good luck... To mark an answer as accepted [see this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#5235) This will also award you with points to your reputation can grow

Answer (score 0):

Changing last part of your query as below should fix the problem.

LEFT JOIN prevents null result set when the column being UNNESTed is null.

```sql
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) as hp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher
```