# BigQuery all columns data of GA analytics

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Is there way to get all the data of GA analytics data while querying Bigquery table. as of now I am able to achieve this upto certain columns but when I am going forward on the same line. I am getting null result.

```
    SELECT visitorId,
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    visitStartTime,
    date,
    totals.visits,
    totals.hits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    totals.bounces,
    totals.transactions,
    totals.transactionRevenue,
    totals.newVisits,
    totals.screenviews,
    totals.uniqueScreenviews,
    totals.timeOnScreen,
    totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
    totals.sessionQualityDim,
    trafficSource.referralPath,
    trafficSource.campaign,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium,
    trafficSource.keyword,
    trafficSource.adContent,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
    trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
    trafficSource.campaignCode,
    device.browser,
    device.browserVersion,
    device.browserSize,
    device.operatingSystem,
    device.operatingSystemVersion,
    device.isMobile,
    device.mobileDeviceBranding,
    device.mobileDeviceModel,
    device.mobileInputSelector,
    device.mobileDeviceInfo,
    device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
    device.flashVersion,
    device.javaEnabled,
    device.language,
    device.screenColors,
    device.screenResolution,
    device.deviceCategory,
    geoNetwork.continent,
    geoNetwork.subContinent,
    geoNetwork.country,
    geoNetwork.region,
    geoNetwork.metro,
    geoNetwork.city,
    geoNetwork.cityId,
    geoNetwork.networkDomain,
    geoNetwork.latitude,
    geoNetwork.longitude,
    geoNetwork.networkLocation,
    h.type,
    h.social.socialInteractionNetwork,
    h.social.socialInteractionAction,
    h.social.socialInteractions,
    h.social.socialInteractionTarget,
    h.social.socialNetwork,
    h.social.uniqueSocialInteractions,
    h.social.hasSocialSourceReferral,
    h.social.socialInteractionNetworkAction,
    h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample,
    h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
    h.latencyTracking.pageDownloadTime,
    h.latencyTracking.redirectionTime,
    h.latencyTracking.speedMetricsSample,
    h.latencyTracking.domainLookupTime,
    h.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime,
    h.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime,
    h.latencyTracking.domLatencyMetricsSample,
    h.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime,
    h.latencyTracking.domContentLoadedTime,
    h.latencyTracking.userTimingValue,
    h.latencyTracking.userTimingSample,
    h.latencyTracking.userTimingVariable,
    h.latencyTracking.userTimingCategory,
    h.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroup3,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroup4,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroup5,
    h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup1,
    h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup2,
    h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup3,
    h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup4,
    h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup5,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews1,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews3,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews4,
    h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews5,
    h.dataSource,
    h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
    h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick,
    h.refund.refundAmount,
    h.refund.localRefundAmount,
    h.eCommerceAction.action_type,
    h.eCommerceAction.step,
    h.eCommerceAction.option,
    h.publisher.dfpClicks,
    h.publisher.dfpImpressions,
    h.publisher.dfpMatchedQueries,
    h.publisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions,
    h.publisher.dfpQueries,
    h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpm,
    h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpc,
    h.publisher.dfpViewableImpressions,
    h.publisher.dfpPagesViewed,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
    h.publisher.adxClicks,
    h.publisher.adxImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxMatchedQueries,
    h.publisher.adxMeasurableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxQueries,
    h.publisher.adxRevenue,
    h.publisher.adxViewableImpressions,
    h.publisher.adxPagesViewed,
    h.publisher.adsViewed,
    h.publisher.adsUnitsViewed,
    h.publisher.adsUnitsMatched,
    h.publisher.viewableAdsViewed,
    h.publisher.measurableAdsViewed,
    h.publisher.adsPagesViewed,
    h.publisher.adsClicked,
    h.publisher.adsRevenue,
    h.publisher.dfpAdGroup,
    h.publisher.dfpAdUnits,
    h.publisher.dfpNetworkId,
    h.hitNumber,
    h.time,
    h.hour,
    h.minute,
    h.isSecure,
    h.isInteraction,
    h.isEntrance,
    h.isExit,
    h.referer,
    h.page.pagePath,

h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.transaction.transactionId,
h.transaction.transactionRevenue as tRevenue,
h.transaction.transactionTax,
h.transaction.transactionShipping,
h.transaction.affiliation,
h.transaction.currencyCode,
h.transaction.localTransactionRevenue,
h.transaction.localTransactionTax,
h.transaction.localTransactionShipping,
h.transaction.transactionCoupon,
h.item.transactionId as tId,
h.item.productName,
h.item.productCategory,
h.item.productSku,
h.item.itemQuantity,
h.item.itemRevenue,
h.item.currencyCode as cCode,
h.item.localItemRevenue,
h.contentInfo.contentDescription,
h.appInfo.name,
h.appInfo.version,
h.appInfo.id,
h.appInfo.installerId,
h.appInfo.appInstallerId,
h.appInfo.appName,
h.appInfo.appVersion,
h.appInfo.appId,
h.appInfo.screenName,
h.appInfo.landingScreenName,
h.appInfo.exitScreenName,
h.appInfo.screenDepth,
h.exceptionInfo.description,
h.exceptionInfo.isFatal,
h.exceptionInfo.exceptions,
h.exceptionInfo.fatalExceptions,
h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
h.eventInfo.eventAction,
h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
h.eventInfo.eventValue

FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
UNNEST(hits) as h
```

I am trying this using python libraries and want to store all the columns data after unnesting into dataframe so that I can convert it into csv. Please let me know is there any possible to get the above thing.

```
SELECT visitorId,
visitNumber,
visitId,
visitStartTime,
date,
totals.visits,
totals.hits,
totals.pageviews,
totals.timeOnSite,
totals.bounces,
totals.transactions,
totals.transactionRevenue,
totals.newVisits,
totals.screenviews,
totals.uniqueScreenviews,
totals.timeOnScreen,
totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
totals.sessionQualityDim,
trafficSource.referralPath,
trafficSource.campaign,
trafficSource.source,
trafficSource.medium,
trafficSource.keyword,
trafficSource.adContent,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
trafficSource.campaignCode,
device.browser,
device.browserVersion,
device.browserSize,
device.operatingSystem,
device.operatingSystemVersion,
device.isMobile,
device.mobileDeviceBranding,
device.mobileDeviceModel,
device.mobileInputSelector,
device.mobileDeviceInfo,
device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
device.flashVersion,
device.javaEnabled,
device.language,
device.screenColors,
device.screenResolution,
device.deviceCategory,
geoNetwork.continent,
geoNetwork.subContinent,
geoNetwork.country,
geoNetwork.region,
geoNetwork.metro,
geoNetwork.city,
geoNetwork.cityId,
geoNetwork.networkDomain,
geoNetwork.latitude,
geoNetwork.longitude,
geoNetwork.networkLocation,
cd.index,
cd.value,
h.hitNumber,
h.time,
h.hour,
h.minute,
h.isSecure,
h.isInteraction,
h.isEntrance,
h.isExit,
h.referer,
h.page.pagePath,
h.page.hostname,
h.page.pageTitle,
h.page.searchKeyword,
h.page.searchCategory,
h.page.pagePathLevel1,
h.page.pagePathLevel2,
h.page.pagePathLevel3,
h.page.pagePathLevel4,
h.transaction.transactionId,
h.transaction.transactionRevenue as tRevenue,
h.transaction.transactionTax,
h.transaction.transactionShipping,
h.transaction.affiliation,
h.transaction.currencyCode,
h.transaction.localTransactionRevenue,
h.transaction.localTransactionTax,
h.transaction.localTransactionShipping,
h.transaction.transactionCoupon,
h.item.transactionId as tId,
h.item.productName,
h.item.productCategory,
h.item.productSku,
h.item.itemQuantity,
h.item.itemRevenue,
h.item.currencyCode as cCode,
h.item.localItemRevenue,
h.contentInfo.contentDescription,
h.appInfo.name,
h.appInfo.version,
h.appInfo.id,
h.appInfo.installerId,
h.appInfo.appInstallerId,
h.appInfo.appName,
h.appInfo.appVersion,
h.appInfo.appId,
h.appInfo.screenName,
h.appInfo.landingScreenName,
h.appInfo.exitScreenName,
h.appInfo.screenDepth,
h.exceptionInfo.description,
h.exceptionInfo.isFatal,
h.exceptionInfo.exceptions,
h.exceptionInfo.fatalExceptions,
h.eventInfo.eventCategory,
h.eventInfo.eventAction,
h.eventInfo.eventLabel,
h.eventInfo.eventValue,
hp.productSKU as pSKU,
hp.v2ProductName,
hp.v2ProductCategory,
hp.productVariant,
hp.productBrand,
hp.productRevenue,
hp.localProductRevenue,
hp.productPrice,
hp.localProductPrice,
hp.productQuantity,
hp.productRefundAmount,
hp.localProductRefundAmount,
hp.isImpression,
hp.isClick,
hpc.index as hpcIndex,
hpc.value as hpcValue,
hpCustomMetrics.index as cusomMetricsIndex,
hpCustomMetrics.value as cusomMetricsValue,
hp.productListName,
hp.productListPosition,
hp.productCouponCode,
hpromotion.promoId, 
hpromotion.promoName,
hpromotion.promoCreative,
hpromotion.promoPosition,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsView,
h.promotionActionInfo.promoIsClick,
h.refund.refundAmount,
h.refund.localRefundAmount,
h.eCommerceAction.action_type,
h.eCommerceAction.step,
h.eCommerceAction.option,
hExperiment.experimentId,
hExperiment.experimentVariant,
h.publisher.dfpClicks,
h.publisher.dfpImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpQueries,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.dfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.dfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.dfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adxClicks,
h.publisher.adxImpressions,
h.publisher.adxMatchedQueries,
h.publisher.adxMeasurableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxQueries,
h.publisher.adxRevenue,
h.publisher.adxViewableImpressions,
h.publisher.adxPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsViewed,
h.publisher.adsUnitsMatched,
h.publisher.viewableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.measurableAdsViewed,
h.publisher.adsPagesViewed,
h.publisher.adsClicked,
h.publisher.adsRevenue,
h.publisher.dfpAdGroup,
h.publisher.dfpAdUnits,
h.publisher.dfpNetworkId,
hcustomVariables.index as hcustomVariableIndex,
hcustomVariables.customVarName,
hcustomVariables.customVarValue,
hcustomDimensions.index as customDimensionsIndex,
hcustomDimensions.value as customDimensionsvalue,
hcustomMetrics.index as hcustoMetricsIndex,
hcustomMetrics.value as hcustomMetricsValue,
h.type,
h.social.socialInteractionNetwork,
h.social.socialInteractionAction,
h.social.socialInteractions,
h.social.socialInteractionTarget,
h.social.socialNetwork,
h.social.uniqueSocialInteractions,
h.social.hasSocialSourceReferral,
h.social.socialInteractionNetworkAction,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadSample,
h.latencyTracking.pageLoadTime,
h.latencyTracking.pageDownloadTime,
h.latencyTracking.redirectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.speedMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domainLookupTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverConnectionTime,
h.latencyTracking.serverResponseTime,
h.latencyTracking.domLatencyMetricsSample,
h.latencyTracking.domInteractiveTime,
h.latencyTracking.domContentLoadedTime,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingValue,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingSample,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingVariable,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingCategory,
h.latencyTracking.userTimingLabel,
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyDisplayName,   
sourcePropertyInfo.sourcePropertyTrackingId,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup1,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup2,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup3,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup4,
h.contentGroup.previousContentGroup5,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews1,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews2,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews3,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews4,
h.contentGroup.contentGroupUniqueViews5,
h.dataSource,
hpublisher.dfpClicks as hpublisherDfpclicks,
hpublisher.dfpImpressions as hpublisherDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.dfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpQueries as hpublisherDfpQueries,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.dfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.dfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.dfpPagesViewed as hpublisherDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsenseBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpClicks as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpClicks,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpQueries as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpQueries,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpm,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpRevenueCpc,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxBackfillDfpPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxBackfillDfpPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adxClicks as hpublisherAdxClicks,
hpublisher.adxImpressions as hpublisherAdxImpressions,
hpublisher.adxMatchedQueries as hpublisherAdxMatchedQueries,
hpublisher.adxMeasurableImpressions as hpublisherAdxMeasurableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxQueries as hpublisherAdxQueries,
hpublisher.adxRevenue as hpublisherAdxRevenue,
hpublisher.adxViewableImpressions as hpublisherAdxViewableImpressions,
hpublisher.adxPagesViewed as hpublisherAdxPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsViewed as hpublisherAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsViewed as hpublisherAdsUnitsViewed,
hpublisher.adsUnitsMatched as hpublisherAdsUnitsMatched,
hpublisher.viewableAdsViewed as hpublisherViewableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.measurableAdsViewed as hpublisherMeasurableAdsViewed,
hpublisher.adsPagesViewed as hpublisherAdsPagesViewed,
hpublisher.adsClicked as hpublisherAdsClicked,
hpublisher.adsRevenue as hpublisherAdsRevenue,
hpublisher.dfpAdGroup as hpublisherDfpAdGroup,
hpublisher.dfpAdUnits as hpublisherDfpAdUnits,
hpublisher.dfpNetworkId as hpublisherDfpNetworkId,
fullVisitorId,
userId,
clientId,
channelGrouping,
socialEngagementType


FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd,
UNNEST(hits) as h,
UNNEST(h.product) as hp,
UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc,
UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics,
UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion,
UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment,
UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables,
UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions,
UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics,
UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher


LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039239/1031958 please check and provide a more detail explanation on why the response not ok

Comment: @Tamir, I have updated my sql that is not working

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your failed query in a simpler way, which should include every column that you want to output.

But it is not necessary, you can still list all columns (if for some reason you want to do this), just avoid UNNESTing several columns like hp.customDimensions and hp.customMetrics (and possibly other columns I removed from your query).

You will see from query below, there's no data in those column and trying to UNNEST them is the reason why you see empty result set.

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT visitorId,
    visitNumber,
    visitId,
    visitStartTime,
    date,
    totals.visits,
    totals.hits,
    totals.pageviews,
    totals.timeOnSite,
    totals.bounces,
    totals.transactions,
    totals.transactionRevenue,
    totals.newVisits,
    totals.screenviews,
    totals.uniqueScreenviews,
    totals.timeOnScreen,
    totals.totalTransactionRevenue,
    totals.sessionQualityDim,
    trafficSource.referralPath,
    trafficSource.campaign,
    trafficSource.source,
    trafficSource.medium,
    trafficSource.keyword,
    trafficSource.adContent,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.campaignId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adGroupId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.creativeId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.page,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.slot,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.criteriaParameters,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.gclId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.customerId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.adNetworkType,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.targetingCriteria.boomUserlistId,
    trafficSource.adwordsClickInfo.isVideoAd,
    trafficSource.isTrueDirect,
    trafficSource.campaignCode,
    device.browser,
    device.browserVersion,
    device.browserSize,
    device.operatingSystem,
    device.operatingSystemVersion,
    device.isMobile,
    device.mobileDeviceBranding,
    device.mobileDeviceModel,
    device.mobileInputSelector,
    device.mobileDeviceInfo,
    device.mobileDeviceMarketingName,
    device.flashVersion,
    device.javaEnabled,
    device.language,
    device.screenColors,
    device.screenResolution,
    device.deviceCategory,
    geoNetwork.continent,
    geoNetwork.subContinent,
    geoNetwork.country,
    geoNetwork.region,
    geoNetwork.metro,
    geoNetwork.city,
    geoNetwork.cityId,
    geoNetwork.networkDomain,
    geoNetwork.latitude,
    geoNetwork.longitude,
    geoNetwork.networkLocation,
    h.* EXCEPT(page, product),
    h.page as hits_page,
    hits_product.* EXCEPT (customDimensions, customMetrics),
    hits_product.customDimensions as hits_product_customDimensions,
    hits_product.customMetrics as hits_product_customMetrics
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801`, 
UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.product) as hits_product
```

The other way of fixing your failed query is changing last part as below. LEFT JOIN prevents null result set when the column being UNNESTed is null.

```sql
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801` 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) as hp
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customDimensions) as hpc
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hp.customMetrics) as hpCustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.promotion) as hpromotion
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.experiment) as hExperiment
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customVariables) as hcustomVariables
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customDimensions) as hcustomDimensions
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.customMetrics) as hcustomMetrics
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.publisher_infos) as hpublisher
```

Comment: @Zhang, Thanks for your input. I will try this and will update you about the result.

Comment: @Zhang, I tried with above, when I have counted the data using above query. the value is different what actually the data have in table.May be by using LEFT JOIN we are missing some data

Comment: I guess it is the contrary that, using LEFT JOIN would give you more data. Consider the example below:
A = [1]
B = NULL

A cross join B = null
A left join B = [1, null]

Comment: @sam from another angel, LEFT JOIN UNNEST(<some_column>)  is always recommended, unless your intention is "No! I don't want this row at all If <some_column> is empty!"

Comment: @Zhang, but In my case I am getting less number of rows by using LEFT JOIN

Comment: @sam it will be helpful if you describe your case (query, results) than just saying "less".  

For example, `select count (*)
FROM bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801 
,UNNEST(hits) as h, UNNEST(h.product) as hp`  ====> **47723** rows.  `select count (*)
FROM bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_20170801 
LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) as h LEFT JOIN UNNEST(h.product) as hp` ====> **51898** rows.

Comment: @Zhang, If we go by LEFT JOIN then are we not duplicating values and impacting our outcomes of result. I don't know much about bigquery, sorry if you find the  question is silly.

Comment: @sam, I feel [BigQuery Tip: The UNNEST Function](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/03/bigquery-tip-unnest-function.html) may help you to understand what is behind the repeated field and what UNNEST really does. Try to play with some shorter examples first.

Comment: Thank you @Zhang I did gone through the above link and based on my understanding. It stats that to get the REPEATED values segregated into different columns. we generally use UNNESTING stuff. so,It means that by using unnest with left join we just segregating the data with out possible data loss and uplication of data.

Comment: I want to point out, without specifying a "join", you still use a default "CROSS JOIN" to UNNESTED data. Please compare CROSS JOIN and LEFT JOIN in your case.

Comment: @Zhang I tried both the approach the data counts are different in both the cases.I just want to make sure that after unnesting. I may not get any duplicates value.